# Mixing DISTINCT with GROUP_BY Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get a list of:

- all months in a specified year that,
- have at least 2 unique rows based on their date
- and ignore specific column values

where I got to is:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('month', "orderDate") AS month, count(*) 
FROM public."Orders"
WHERE "companyId" = 00001 AND "orderNumber" != 1 and DATE_PART('year', ("orderDate")) = '2020' AND "orderNumber" != NULL
GROUP BY month
HAVING COUNT ("orderDate") > 2
```

The `HAVING_COUNT` sort of works in place of `DISTINCT` insofar as I can be reasonably sure that condition filters the condition of data required.
However, being able to use DISTINCT based on a given date within a month would return a more reliable result. Is this possible with Postgres?

A sample line of data from the table:

Sample Input

```
"2018-12-17 20:32:00+00"
"2019-02-26 14:38:00+00"
"2020-07-26 10:19:00+00"
"2020-10-13 19:15:00+00"
"2020-10-26 16:42:00+00"
"2020-10-26 19:41:00+00"
"2020-11-19 20:21:00+00"
"2020-11-19 21:22:00+00"
"2020-11-23 21:10:00+00"
"2021-01-02 12:51:00+00"
```

without the `HAVING_COUNT` this produces

| month | count |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 11 | 3 |

Month 7 can be discarded easily as only 1 record.
Month 10 is the issue: we have two records. But from the data above, those records are from the **same day**. Similarly, month 11 only has 2 distinct records by day.

The output should therefore be ideally:

| month | count |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 2 |

We have only two distinct dates from the 2020 data, and they are from month 11 (November)

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated

Comment: Sample line of data won't help much.  We need to see a handful of _input_ records, along with the output, and an explanation of the output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ah, apologies, I did wonder how the schema would help :/ make much more sense. edited.

Comment: Thanks for the edits.  I was able to provide an answer below.  Lesson learned: For SQL questions on this site, showing sample data may be critical to getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to take the distinct count of dates for each month:

```sql
SELECT
    DATE_PART('month', orderDate) AS month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT orderDate::date) AS count
FROM Orders
WHERE
    companyId = 1 AND
    orderNumber != 1 AND
    DATE_PART('year', orderDate) = '2020'
GROUP BY
    DATE_PART('month', orderDate)
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT orderDate::date) > 2;
```

Comment: Great, thank you and for the edit prompts - definitely will help for framing any future SQL questions